# hphpize not working when trying install hhvm mongo driver

Tags: mongodb, hhvm

I was trying to install mongo driver for hhvm.

At some time, I have to install hhvm-dev so I can use hphpize later. This thing is that when I try to run hphpize, it returns "hphpize: command not found", even after install hhvm-dev.

Did anyone have the same problem?

Driver documentation here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hhvm-driver

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use your package manager to determine the set of files that `hhvm-dev` installed. If `hphpize` is included, add the directory where it is located to `PATH`. If not included, you may need to install some other package.